# Aggregating multiple encoded categorical values

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, categorical-data, encoding

I am trying find commonly used techniques when dealing with high cardinality multi-valued categorical variables.

I am currently using a dataset with a feature **CATEGORY** which has a cardinality of ~20,000. One-hot encoding does not make sense has it would increase the feature space by too much.

Each observation in my dataset can take multiple values for the **CATEGORY** feature, for instance, row 1 could have the value **a** but row 2 could have the values **a, b, c, d**

I have managed to encode each individual value in the feature but am unsure how to aggregate these values for each row.

How should these encoded values be combined?

Answer (score 0):

If individual categories are important in your analysis, you could split the category column into multiple columns based on the amount of different category values then pivot your data set to have multiple row entries per category.

Visually

```
recordid | category | value
-------- | -------- | -----
   1     |   a      |  5
   2     |   a,b,c  |  10
```

would become

```
recordid | category |  value
-------- | -------- | ------
   1     |   a      |   5
   2     |   a      |   10
   2     |   b      |   10
   2     |   c      |   10
```

You could then make further aggregations or transformations as necessary.

Otherwise you could consider "a" and "abc" and "abcd" a new category, i.e. an item with categories "abc" is different from an item with just the category "a"

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is to use the `min_frequency` parameter of SK-learn's OneHotEncoder, check it out : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

You give it a minimal number of observations to reach for the value to have its own one-hot feature. All values that do not reach this minimum are rare values and will be grouped in an infrequent_category.

Say you set it to 100, then it's perfectly acceptable to have a lot of one-hot features because all of them will have more than 100 observations.